# matching regex in awk/gawk

Tags: regex, awk, regex-greedy

Can someone make the `awk` line below work in awk please. The syntax uses the standard PCRE regex standard (and i need to expect that some non-numeric characters are preceded to the first number, that is the string can look like `"++3.59  ±   0.04* "`). (note that I tried `[0-9]` and `[:digit:]` instead of `\d`) also note that I did read https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Regexp

```
gawk 'BEGIN{test="3.59 ± 0.04";match(test, /^.*?(\d+?\.\d+?)\s*?±\s*?(\d+?\.\d+?)$/, arr);print arr[1];}'
```

Comment: POSIX regex engine does not support lazy quantifiers. Go on trying with `[0-9]` to match digits, `\d` is not supported. Also, use `[ \t]` or `[[:space:]]` instead of `\s`.

Comment: PCRE is not standard at all. Your best bet is to use Perl instead.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew And in POSIX standard, is `*` greedy or lazy then?

Comment: It is always greedy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you add to many `?` and I think you need to use `[0-9]`
Also when you start with `^[^0-9]` only non-numeric characters are "eaten away".
so in summary I think you want:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{test="3.59 ± 0.04";match(test, /^[^0-9.]*([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\s*±\s*([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)$/, arr);print arr[1];}
```

That matches any non-numeric character up to the first numeric one and then captures the first number as group 1.

Thanks @Ed Morton for the corrections. I did miss the `+` after the first digit in the original regex.

Comment: The meaning of `*?`, `+?`, and `??` in PCRE is that it switches from greedy to stingy matching. This cannot easily be reimplemented with traditional always-greedy regex like Awk's, though it's not clear how exactly the OP thinks this construct is useful here.